# Bitmap in some cells of a DataGridView column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bitmap

I have a complete dataGridView with 5 Columns.

Now, I want to draw a Bitmap in certains cells of these columns.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

I've currently tried:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(   ) ;
```

Can you help me to draw a bitmap in new Row of dataGridView.Rows?

Comment: Is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: Where is the bitmap coming from?  How do you want it drawn in the `DataGridView`?  That line of code alone won't do anything related to a bitmap, it'll just add a new row.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, what the `DataGridView` currently looks like and how you want it modified?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do here. Do you want one row with just images in your grid, while the rest of the content for you columns is something else? This is unusual behaviour for the DataGridView but can probably be done.

Comment: please past a code. Please..... my image saving in Resource of program

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo you haven't yet given enough information to answer the question. Please try and explain better what it is you need - what code have your tried, what do you want the grid to look like?

Comment: look like this.http://soft-87.persiangig.com/datagrid.PNG

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo So you want some of your cells to have images while other cells (in the same column) have text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("columnName1", "Column 1 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("columnName2", "Column 2 Header");

var row1 = new DataGridViewRow();
row1.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewImageCell { Value = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\to\image.jpg") });
row1.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = "string" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);

var row2 = new DataGridViewRow();
row2.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = "string"});
row2.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewImageCell { Value = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\to\image.jpg") });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row2);
```